# @ControlerAdvice not working in spring boot (latest)

Tags: spring-boot, controller-advice

I try to intercept custom exception with @ControllerAdvice annotation.

This is code:

```
@ControllerAdvice(basePackages = "{com.ciro.cotroller}")
@RestController
public class RestResponseEntityExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(value = {TodoNotFoundException.class})
    public final ResponseEntity<ExceptionResponse> todoNotFoundException(TodoNotFoundException exception){
        ExceptionResponse exceptionResponse = new ExceptionResponse(exception.getMessage(), "custom details");
        return new ResponseEntity<ExceptionResponse>(exceptionResponse,HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
}
```

This is my exception:

```
package com.ciro.exception;

public class TodoNotFoundException extends RuntimeException {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public TodoNotFoundException() {
        throw new RuntimeException("An custom error is raised!");
    }
}
```

But default entity response is returned.

Answer (score 1):

I changed the code in this way and all works fine.

```
public TodoNotFoundException() {
    super();
}
```

First error was in the exception's constructor. I need  to invoke super method and not throws runtime exception.

```
@ControllerAdvice("com.ciro.cotroller")
```

The second is base package.